# $\sum_n |f(x_n)| < \infty \ \forall f \in X^* \implies \sum_n |f(x_n)| < C \|f\|$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am working on the following problem

> Let $X$ be a normed space, and let $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}\in X$, and suppose that $\sum_n |f(x_n)| < \infty \ \forall f \in X^*$ Prove that $\sum_n |f(x_n)| < C \|f\| \ \forall f \in X^*$.

What I've done so far. By considering the set $A =\{\hat{x}_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $\hat{x}_n$ is the canonical embedding of $\hat{x}_n$ into $X^{**}$, I can apply the principle of uniform boundedness to $A$, to conclude that the maps $\hat{x}_n$ are uniformly bounded. However, this only gives that $|f(x_i)| \leq C \|f\|$ which is not very helpful I think. I also tried extending $A$ to contain sums of the form $x_1+\cdots + x_n$, which works similarly, and I get $|f(x_1 + \cdots + x_n)| \leq C \|f\|$, but again I don't really know how to finish this either.
I also tried to consider the map $F:X^* \to \mathbb{R}$, given by $f \left(\sum_n x_n \right)$ , which I believe is well-defined and linear, and then apply the closed graph theorem, but again, I didn't succeed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you may consider the map from $X^*$ to $\ell^1$ given by the formula $f\mapsto \{f(x_n)\}$ and then apply the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: What should I apply the UBP to?

Comment: The explanation is in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Consider the operators $T_n: X^*\to \ell^1$ defined by $$T_n(f)=(f(x_1),f(x_2),\ldots, f(x_n),0,\ldots)$$ Clearly the operators $T_n$ are bounded. By assumptions  the operators $T_n$ are bounded pointwise. Thus by the uniform boundedness theorem they are uniformly bounded, i.e. $$\sum_{k=1}^n|f(x_k)| =\|T_n(f)\|_1\le C\|f\|$$ for a constant independent of $n.$ As $n$ is arbitrary we get the conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, define a linear operator $T:X^*\to\ell^1$ by $T(f)=(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Note that you are actually asked to prove that $T$ is bounded. Since $X^*$ and $\ell^1$ are both Banach spaces, we can indeed apply the closed graph theorem. So assume $f_k\to f$ in $X^*$, and $T(f_k)\to y=(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. We want to show that $T(f)=y$.

We know that $||T(f_k)-y||_1=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|f_k(x_n)-y_n|\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. This of course implies that for each specific $n$ we have $f_k(x_n)\to y_n$ as $k\to\infty$. But on the other hand, $f_k\to f$ in $X^*$, which in particular implies the much weaker condition $f_k(x_n)\to f(x_n)$. So indeed $f(x_n)=y_n$.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, I will leave an answer using the Banach-Steinhaus theorem too, which is a slight twist on Ryszard Szwarc's answer.

Let $T: X^* \to \ell^1$ given by $f \to \{f(x_n\}$. As noted in their answer, the maps $T_n$ are clearly bounded, further, for any $f \in X^*$ we have $T_n(f) \to T(f)$. Thus by Banach-Steinhaus $T$ is a continuous linear map, and hence the claim follows.